# Django: How to wrapper a file stream if I want to process it in the app

Tags: django, file, stream

It seems like that file stream is firstly saved in webserver, and then returned to app. I want to  return the file stream directly to app, so I can skip the step of save it on webserver, and I can still use the same format of request.FILES to get the stream, and then process it.  How to wrapper the file stream ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that would be setting of webserver related to how to handle uploaded files.

Answer (score -1):

While Web servers do expose APIs with which you can access the progress of receiving a request, it's not possible to return a response for a partially received request—your application will not be passed a request until it's been fully transmitted.

Additionally, you would never want the application itself to be responsible for handling the uploads. That would mean that your expensive 80MB thread is going to be locked for the duration a client is sending a request with a large body, which would make it trivial to create enough requests to lock all your threads into handling file uploads and cause a denial of service attack.

I'm not exactly sure what your issue is with Web servers handling file uploads, but you should note that in all cases these uploads are stored in a temporary location. Please let the Web server do what it does best.